# Could we burninate [statement]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I've just come across an excerpt [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1053705) for [statements](/questions/tagged/statements):

> In computer programming a statement is the smallest standalone element
>   of an imperative programming language. A program written in such a
>   language is formed by a sequence of one or more statements. A
>   statement will have internal components (e.g., expressions).

This seems to be partially lifted from the one for [statement](/questions/tagged/statement):

> In an imperative programming language, a program is a sequence of
>   statements, which are the smallest isolated components of a program.
>   In constrast to expressions, statements are mainly executed for their
>   side effects, not for their return value.

I can't really see any value in this tag at all. If almost everything is a statement this could be applied to almost every question?

Could we burninate this; or, at the very least merge and synonymise [statements](/questions/tagged/statements) and [statement](/questions/tagged/statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with clarifying this tag. In particular, a statement could also be:

- A [sql-statement](/questions/tagged/sql-statement) (which is a synonym tag for [sql](/questions/tagged/sql))
- An account statement (no tag yet)
- A [citation](/questions/tagged/citation) of someone who stated something
- etc.

With all this ambiguity, [statement](/questions/tagged/statement) and [statements](/questions/tagged/statements) don't really add any clear information to a question.